# How to detect in EKEventStore when the app is closed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ekevent

In my app, I am fetching EKEventStore for events and saving them locally in CoreData for the very first time when user runs the app.
For this point on i only want to fetch events from EventStore when there is any changes in the event store.

I used EKEventStoreChangedNotification and it works fine when ever i add an event in the calendar while my app is in background. But it doesn't work when the app is closed.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc]init];
    [self.eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted) {

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                     selector:@selector(storeChanged:)
                                                         name:EKEventStoreChangedNotification
                                                       object:self.eventStore];
        }
    }];
return YES;
}

-(void)storeChanged:(NSNotification *)notif {

    // Update core data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put a observer in

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

}
```

Your AppDelegate?

Comment: I guess this will only take care when my app is in background and runnig but what about when my app is not even running (not even in the background)

Comment: There is no chance to react on new events when your app is not active. Your have to check EKEventStore every time when you run the app.